# How can I protect the loopback explorer by username and password?

Tags: node.js, api, loopback, loopback4

I've just started using loopback4 and I would like to protect the /explorer from being public. The user would initially see a page where username and password must be entered. If successful, the user is redirected to /explorer where he can see all API methods (and execute them). If user is not authenticated, accessing the path /explorer would give a response of "Unauthorized". Is there a way to easily implement this?

Answer (score 0):

There is issue talking about a GLOBAL default strategy is enabled for all routes including explorer in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5758

The way is to specify a global metadata through the options:

```
this.configure(AuthenticationBindings.COMPONENT).to({
  defaultMetadata: {
    strategy: 'JWTStrategy'
  }
})
this.component(AuthenticationComponent);
registerAuthenticationStrategy(this, JWTAuthenticationStrategy)
```

But in terms of enabling a single endpoint added by `route.get()`, it's not supported yet, see [code of how explorer is registered](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest/src/rest.server.ts#L322). `@loopback/authentication` retrieves auth strategy name from a controller class or its members, but if the route is not defined in the controller, it can only fall back to the default options, see [implementation](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/authentication/src/providers/auth-metadata.provider.ts#L45)